# Servlet in eclipse+tomcat dont works [Error 404]

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

i'm trying to develop simple API servlet with Eclipse & Tomcat.
when i access the link http://localhost:8080/MosheAPI_Project/rest/hello
i get error 404.

this is my servlet code & web.xml:
***MyCode

```
package MyPackage;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@Path("/hello")
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayHelloXML() {
        String resource="<? xml version='1.0' ?> "+
        "<hello> Hi Moshe </hello>";
        return resource;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHelloHTML() {
        String resource="<h1>SFGSFG</h1>";
        return resource;
    }
}
```

**** web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>MosheAPI_Project</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MosheAPI_Project</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class</servlet-class>
        <!-- <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>  -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MosheAPI_Project</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

[Here is the result in eclipse:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BLmi.png)

Comment: when you specify a class, it should not have the trailing `.class` -- just the package and the class name. You are not referencing your `HelloWorld` class from `web.xml` -- what are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You are using two mapping for the same servlet, but as you can read in [this](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/servlet-3-0-how-to-override-webservlet-mappings/) article you can access your servlet using http://localhost:8080/MosheAPI_Project/hello, but if you didn't add @WebServlet to your servlet then you can access it the way you are now.

BTW you didn't extend  HttpServlet  in your servlet which doesn't make it a servlet after all.